# ¿Por que me sale el error: 'else' without 'if'?

Tags: java

En la parte del segundo ELSE en el CASE 1 me aparece el error "else without if" .

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class PruebaAdmonPersonal {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
      int opc, id, horasContrato, celda, dato, resp;
      String nombre, fechaNac, puesto;
      char  sexo;
      AdmonPersonal ap = new AdmonPersonal();
      Personal p;
      
       
       
        do{
        
         System.out.println("\nCATALGO DE MA");
         System.out.println("[1] ALTAS");
         System.out.println("[2] CONSULTA INDIVIDUAL");
         System.out.println("[3] CONSULTA GENERAL");
         System.out.println("[4] MODIFICACIONES");
         System.out.println("[5] BAJAS");
         System.out.println("[6] FINALIZAR");
         System.out.println("¿Opcion deseada? [1-6]: ");
         opc = leer.nextInt();
         switch(opc) {
            case 1: //ALTAS
            if(ap.hayEspacio()) {
               System.out.print("ingrese el id del maestro a dar de alta");
               id= leer.nextInt();
               if(ap.validarId(id)) {
              
            } else {
               System.out.println("El id no es valido, ingrese uno del en el rango 1-100... presione ENTER para continuar");
               leer.nextLine(); leer.nextLine();
               
            } else {//aqui aparece el error without if 
               System.out.println("Base de datos llena,presione ENTER para continuar");
               leer.nextLine(); leer.nextLine();
             }
           } 
           break;
            case 2: //CONSULTA INDIVIDUAL
               break;
            case 3: //CONSULTA GENERAL
               break;
            case 4: //MODIFICACIONES
               break;
            case 5: //BAJAS
               break;
            case 6: //FINALIZAR
               System.out.println("\nProgramador: " +"Julio Adriel Velázquez  Ponce");
               System.out.println("14-octubre-2021");
               System.out.println("Gracias por utilizar el CATALOGO DE MAESTROS");
               break;
            default:
               System.out.println("Opcion no valida...Presiona ENTER para continuar");
               leer.nextLine(); leer.nextLine(); //Pausa
         }         
       
      } while(opc != 6);
      }
     }
```

Comment: Porque te faltó cerrar la llave del primer `if` antes del último `else`. Lo estás colocando justo después, cuando tiene que ir antes.

Comment: Pues me juego la vida a que es porque has puesto un else que no corresponde a ningún if. Miro tu código y veo dos elses seguidos. El segundo de ellos es el que dices que falla. Por favor, usa un editor que te coloree el código e identifique parejas de paréntesis y llaves. Y formatea el código correctamente, sobretodo las tabulaciones. Y, si te vuelve a pasar, seguro que podrás identificar por ti mismo dónde te despistaste con facilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema esta en la hora de cerrar los paréntesis de los if else del case 1. Primero ten cuidado con las tabulaciones porque con ellas es mas fácil identificar donde termina un if y empieza el siguiente y segundo fíjate donde abres y cierras los corchetes de los if else, ya que tu primer `if(ap.hayEspacio())` engloba a todo tu case 1 y ese es tu error. Este seria tu codigo con las tabulaciones y corchetes bien puestos:

```
 case 1: //ALTAS
                if(ap.hayEspacio()) {
                   System.out.print("ingrese el id del maestro a dar de alta");
                   id= leer.nextInt();
                   if(ap.validarId(id)) {
                  
                   }else {
                   System.out.println("El id no es valido, ingrese uno del en el rango 1-100... presione ENTER para continuar");
                   leer.nextLine(); leer.nextLine();
                   } 
                }else {//aqui aparece el error without if 
                   System.out.println("Base de datos llena,presione ENTER para continuar");
                   leer.nextLine(); leer.nextLine();
                 }
               break;
```

Comment: muchas gracias! si me sirvió y ya identifique el porque